# Spring Spring-JS vs JQuery form submit

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow, spring-js

I am working on a Spring Webflow project that was builded with Spring-JS but the firm is requesting me to change the following code to use JQuery.  I am NOT a JavaScript/JQuery programmer so I do need some help with now..

Below is working code that on a change of a selectbox (called borough) it will change the _eventID(need it for webflow) to loadSchools and then do a form submit of everything on the pages.  I been trying for days to get this working in JQuery but nothing is working

Below is the old working code using Spring-JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.AjaxEventDecoration({
                        elementId: "borough",
                        formId: 'member',
                        event: "onchange",
                        params: {_eventId: 'loadSchools', fragments: 'contents'}

                    }));
</script>
```

Here is the code I been working on that DON'T work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#borough").change(function() {
            $('input[name="_eventId"]').val('loadSchools').appendTo('#member');
            $('#member').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly happens with the JQuery version?

Answer (score 0):

Spring-JS is bound against Dojo. They never supported anything other than Dojo 1.5.0. If you want to use jQuery, you'll have to stop using Spring Webflow's integration with Spring-JS.

See the [Spring Forum thread](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/roo/92172-change-version-of-dojo-in-my-project?view=stream).